# Architect an API layer

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf

Broad, general question:

We have an app that is quickly approaching legacy status. It has three clients: Windows app, browser (web site) and mobile.  The data access layer is convoluted at best and has grown organically over the years.

We want to re-architect the whole thing.  The Windows app will go away ('cause who does *that* any more?)  We will only have the browser based website and the mobile app, both of which will consume the (as of today, non-existant) API layer.  This API layer will also be partially exposed to third parties should they wish to do their own integrations.

Here's my question:

What does this API layer look like?  And by that, I mean... let's start in the Visual Studio solution.  Is the API a separate website?  So on IIS, will there be two sites... one for the public facing website and another for the API layer?

Or, should the API be a .dll within the main website, and have the endpoint URL's be part of the single website in IIS?

Eventually, we will want to update and publish one w/o impacting the other.  I'm just unsure, on a very high level, how to structure the entire thing.

(If it matters:  Each client has their own install, either locally on their network, or cloud hosted.  All db's are single tenant.)

Comment: Ah geesh - if you are going to vote to close this, you could as least give me a reason why.  Isn't this website all about teaching people?

Comment: No, this website is a Q&A about programming questions. As you yourself state, it is a broad, general question (maybe even opinion based). See https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: It depends on what your API is supposed to do. If it is only meant to be used for data transfer, then it is best to be developed as web services (let's say WCF). Web services can be deployed either on the same server as the application server, or on a different server (that makes your app  scale-able), but the deployment would become a little bit more complex

Comment: This question appears to be better suited for the Software Engineering community of StackExchange due to focus on architecture.

Answer (score 2):

I would think one single solution with multiple projects.

If you put the API as a different site, you can easily add something like Swagger and Swashbuckle to your API
https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle

This will make documentation easy.

From here you would want to put your business logic (the things that do specific things) in a third project.

From here you have two options. The webpage can consume your own API, or you can reference your business logic project.

API on a different site offers some additional benefit if it is public facing:
Separation of domain
Load balancing and added protection
Resource limiting and throttling without site impact

These kinds of projects are a lot of fun, so consider your options and what will fit best.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, that helps a lot.  Thank you for being willing to share and teach!

Answer (score 2):

my preferd way of doing this is with an seperate API project. you publisch the API project to one url and the website to another. this lets you develop both applications with no interferance.

that said, I normaly put the logic of the API in a Service layer (SOA architecture). My api project just pass the input to the sercice layer and response with the service response. this way you can seperate the api between public and private and still contain all the logic in one place.

usally i create a Api wrapper as a seperate project to handle all API calls, so other devs can use the API wrapper (just to make talking to the api more easy for my feelow devs)

Comment: Ok, that makes sense.  Much appreciated!